# In Python, how to count all the documents in MongoDB containing specific status?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Using the following release model, how can I write a query in python to get all the releases whose status are set to **`Finished`**?

```
relStatus = ("Planning", "Pending Approval", "Assigning Testers", "Testing", "Cancelled", "Finished")

class Release(db.Document):
    release_name = db.StringField(max_length=80, required=True)
    description = db.StringField(max_length=160, required=True)
    start_date = db.DateTimeField(required=True)
    end_date = db.DateTimeField(required=True)
    status = db.StringField(default="Planning", choices=relStatus)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.release_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.release_name
```

I'm using PyMongo as a connection driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get result from mongodb using simple query as:

```
result = mongo.db.collection_name.find({'status':'Finished'},{'_id':False}})
result = list(result)
print(result)
```